# Android Studio 1.2.1.1 "cannot resolve symbol" android in the import statement com.google.android.*

Tags: android, android-studio

Title pretty much describes the issue. If you need any more specifics let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What is the complete import statement? are you working with maps or Google play services?¡

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some library references, you need to add the libraries from the SDK,
Read more about

[**Referencing a library project**](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

and

[**Setting Up Google Play Services**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and this resolved it.:

Open build.gradle (in app) change the `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'` try using 
`21.0.1`, `23.0.1 rc1`. What finally worked for me was 21.0.1

OR

Go to `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `App` - > `Properties` (Shortcut Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) -> Change the Build Tools Version and press `OK`

If this doesn't solve the problem.
Go to `Build -> Clean Project` and `Build -> Rebuild Project` before you sync the project with gradle.

Also in the `build.gradle` in app check the dependencies you should have something like this :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'// This is for GCM service
}
```